# How to formulate a zero sum game?

Tags: matrices, game-theory

So i have this question:[image]

To formulate a zero sum game, these are my assumptions:

- B,C,D=1,1,1 and a > 0.

-p1 is the guard and p2 is the burglar.

-p1 goes on the rows and p2 goes on the columns.

-if p1 wins, he gets a payoff of a , and if p2 looses he gets a payoff of -a.

- ABCD are the corresponding row labels and column labels..

First of all, are these assumptions correct?

Then i wanted to analyze the first column.

If P1 is in A, and P2 is in A, then **P1** gets an outcome of a?

If P1 is in B, and p2 is in A, then **P1** gets an outcome of -a?

If my ideas are correct, then the matrix represents the payoffs of P1, the guard, instead of the payoffs of the burglar. Then if P1 doesn't win, his payoff should be -a too if he is in the a room.

Should this be right?

Moroever, why are the a values only in the first column? For example, in the first row second column, since player 1 is in a but player 2 is in b, shouldn't the value still be -a?

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Seems to me that the bottom right number should be +1 rather than -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third of your interpretations/assumptions is wrong. It should be: "If $P1$ wins then $P1$ receives $a$ if $P2$ is in $A$, otherwise he receives $1$." The entries in the matrix can be thought of as the payout for $P1$. Negative entries correspond to cases where $P1$ looses. In those cases the entries represent the negative of what $P2$ wins.

If $P1$ is in $A$ and $P2$ in $A$ then the thieve is caught resulting in a payout of $a$ for $P1$. If $P1$ is in $B$ and $P2$ in $A$ then the thieve is not caught as $A$ is not adjacent to $B$. Hence $P2$ gets payout of $a$ and this is represented by the value $-a$ in the matrix.

In the second to fourth column the values are either $1$ or $-1$ because in those cases the burglar finds himself in one of the rooms $B, C, D$. In those rooms objects have value $1$ and thus either the guard or the burglar get payout $1$.

Comment: Thank you ! i greatly appreciate you helping me in my excercises